# Paypal Transparent Checkout using Flutter

Tags: flutter, paypal, checkout

I am searching to check if its possible to create a transparent checkout using Paypal + Flutter

at this moment I have this module

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paypal

but there is no references about transparent checkout

Reading the documentation I can see that is possible with Paypal plus, but I didn't found any flutter module to handle it

I can do it using webview, but not sure if there is any restrictions to publish

Does anyone knows any alternatives to this?